# UITableView not scrolling enough after expanding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `UIView` at the bottom. (using storyboard). My `UIView` is set to hidden and changes state afterwards  on click of button. First, I was trying to resize (increase height basically) my UIView on `IBAction`(buttonClick) using `self.concluidoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);` but UIView was disappearing instead.

Now, it is correctly expanding `UIView` with the following code inside `IBAction`:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect frame = self.concluidoView.frame;
                         frame.size.height += 100.0;
                         self.concluidoView.frame = frame;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         // complete

                     }];
```

The problem is that my UITableViewController is not scrolling enough to the new size, since the `UIView` is the last item in my `tableView`.

I've tried a few things to solve this problem, including manually trying to resize `tableview` to increase it's height to the same value of the `UIView`increase. I used the following code:

```
CGRect tableFrame = self.tableview.frame;
        tableFrame.size.height += 100;
        self.tableView.frame = tableFrame;
        [self.tableview layoutIfNeeded];
```

The scrolling capacity of my `tableview`was actually smaller after this code. I would like to resize `tableview`and allow scrolling, either manually, since I know how much my `subview`will increase, or automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `UITableView`'s frame, all you'll do is make it extend off screen most likely. What you want to do is get the table view to recognize that the `UIView` is larger. I'm assuming this `UIView` is the `tableFooterView` of your `UITableView`. Try doing the following:

```
UIView *footerView = self.tableView.tableFooterView;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

That will force the `UITableView` to reexamine the size of the footer view. I've had to do this before when changing the size of a footer view before.

Comment: Perfect! This did the job, I had my `UIView`in a `@property`, so I just assigned the `tableFooterView`to it. Thanks.